# How do I create a wix3.5 installer to check for VS2010 and install it if its not installed

Tags: installation, wix, wix3.5

In my installer I need to check whether VS2010 is present on the machine while I run the msi. If its not present, I need to provide a link to install VS2010.

How to accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you need to install Visual Studio? If you need a specific runtime (Visual C++, .NET Framework etc.), you can install just the redistributable.

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose you can use one of the properties defined in the [WiX Visual Studio extension](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wixvsextension.htm).

Comment: Or add VC runtime merge modules to MSI. This way the runtime libraries are installed automatically with the product.